# Find the index in a single array of a Cartesian coordinate

Tags: c#, math, cartesian-coordinates

I'm trying to figure out something that should be very simple yet, for some reason I just can't find the answer.  I've been trying out formulas for the past few hours now.  Take a Cartesian coordinate system of a grid 10 by 10 so 0,0 to 10,10.  Each coordinate has a float assigned to it (determining height) and they have been read into a float[] row by row first row (0,0) to (10,0) second row (0,1) to (10,1).  Now I want to write a helper method, to fetch the height of a certain Cartesian coordinate fe: (10, 0).  That float would reside at index 9 in the float[] and (0, 1) would reside at index 10.  I've tried several attempts but each time (0, 0) is being a stubborn mule.  Here are some of the formulas I tried.

```
Z = (Y * 10 + X) 
  works for 0, 0 but not really for 10, 0 cause that index should be 9
Z = ((Y * 10 + X) - 1) 
  works for 10, 0 but well not for 0, 0
```

I tried a few more complicated once but can't recall them now since my notepad where I wrote them down has closed without saving.  I would appreciate if someone can put me in the right direction, but please use simple math explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your grid is 10 by 10, then it's from (0,0) to (9,9).
A row from (0,0) to (10,0) means 11 items in a row, so your function should be:

```
Z = (Y * 11 + X)
```

Comment: Oh my I see where I've been looking wrong the entire time.  Some context I'm reading in a bitmap as heightfield and I assumed that pixel one started at (0,0) and ended at (10,0).  But ofcourse that is wrong the last pixel is (9,0).  Damn I'm feeling a bit embarrassed now to have put this question on stackoverflow ....